# how to convert following java code to java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, guava

I write java code like this ,

```
 private DateTime getChangedDoseEndDate(final DateTime actualTerminateDate, final DateTime discontinueDate)
  {
    if (actualTerminateDate == null)
    {
      return discontinueDate;
    }

    if (discontinueDate == null)
    {
      return actualTerminateDate;
    }
    else if (actualTerminateDate.isBefore(discontinueDate))
    {
      return actualTerminateDate;
    }
    else
    {
      return discontinueDate;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to it convert Guava , to write single line function.
This is ,I tried one. Is it correct ? I also need to it convert java 8 .

```
return Ordering.natural().nullsLast().min(discontinueDate, actualTerminateDate);
```

Comment: why guava? you can do that with java-8 only.

Comment: @Eugene it is  best can do it only using java 8 . can u help me ?

Comment: `Stream.of(actualTerminateDate, discontinueDate).min(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())))
              .orElseThrow(() -> ....)` I guess...

Comment: Do you want to simplify your code or are you interested in Java8/Guava one-liner specifically?

Comment: @Podarkes , i am interested convert it java 8 ,can u help me

Comment: Check this, it's a valid Java 8 code. 
`return terminateDate != null && terminateDate.isBefore(discontinueDate) ? terminateDate : discontinueDate;`
If you are interested, I can write a more detailed answer with my reasoning. As to your Guava code, it works perfectly and covers all cases the initial method has.

Comment: @Eugene seriously, `Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())`? What about `Comparator.naturalOrder()`?

Comment: @Podarkes ,yes , if u can put more detail answer it may be very help full .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your code more succinct, you have other means to do so, unless you want just to show off with a one-liner. Here is one of the ways to approach it. It's not a one-liner and it's not using any lambdas either, but it's still a valid Java 8 code and it has the same logic, but expressed in a more simple way.

```
DateTime getChangedDoseEndDate(final DateTime actualTerminateDate, final DateTime discontinueDate) {
  if (actualTerminateDate != null && actualTerminateDate.isBefore(discontinueDate)) {
    return actualTerminateDate;
  }
  return discontinueDate;
}
```

You can even use ternary operator and fit it in a one-liner (and it's still a valid Java 8 code).

```
DateTime getChangedDoseEndDate(final DateTime terminateDate, final DateTime discontinueDate) {
  return terminateDate != null && terminateDate.isBefore(discontinueDate) ? terminateDate : discontinueDate;
}
```

However, if you can guarantee null safety, you may have something similar to Guava's code of yours (which is working perfectly, since you asked).

```
DateTime getChangedDoseEndDate(@Nonnull final DateTime actualTerminateDate, @Nonnull final DateTime discontinueDate) {
  return Stream.of(actualTerminateDate, discontinueDate).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
}
```